# PLSQL: How to know space utilization by Selected records

Tags: oracle11g

We are planning to archive older data from some tables.  But before doing so we have to estimate how much space will we gain once we purge older records.

For Example, suppose we have an ORDERS table which is consuming 5Gb of space on disk. We have more than 15 Million records in this table. We are interested in keeping records after 2010. When we query for records before 2010, we have got approx 12 Million of records and we are in planning of archiving and purging these records.

We have to first calculate how much free space will we gain when we remove these 12 million records. How can we calculate space consumed by such selected records.

One way which i can thought of is by creating a new table for these 12 Million old records and then calculate its segment size.

Please suggest if we can still calculate space of the selected records in much better way. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need PL/SQL for this. A simple `select sum(vsize(column_1) + vsize(column_2) + ....) from table where ...` will show you the size for all rows.

Comment: You're removing 12 million out of 15 million, which is 80% of the rows; so you'll save roughly 80% of the space, which is 4GB? Or do you need an exact figure? You also need to think about what free space means - the segments will still be allocated to the table unless you shrink/move/rebuild it, but will be available for new rows in the same table. You won't save any actual disk space unless you resize the data files, which isn't necessarily simple. .

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, it worked :)

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole for your valuable inputs. understood your point that just deleting the records will not allow the space to be used by other tables but only by mu ORDERS table. I shall surly bring this point during discussion within team. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the space of the selected records, you can try as below:

step 1 :

```
scott@dev8i> analyze table orders compute statistics;
Table analyzed.
```

OR as per Ben sugesstion

```
scott@dev8i> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('<SHCEMA>', 'ORDERS');
```

Step 2:

```
scott@dev8i> select num_rows * avg_row_len
             from dba_tables
             where table_name = 'ORDERS';


NUM_ROWS*AVG_ROW_LEN
--------------------
      560      ---This is the total table size.
```

The result of the query shows that the `Orders` table is using 560 bytes of the total bytes allocated to it.

Since you want how much space is allocated to 12 million records, then you just need to replace `num_rows` with 12000000. The result will be the approximate figure in bytes.

Comment: The `analyze` command is deprecated in favour of [`DBMS_STATS`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm)...

Comment: @Ben..Incorporated your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @Raj_Te really helpful.